# Error in enabling a selector using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to enable a multi selector only when a checkbox is checked. My code is generating an alert, but won't enable the selector

Selector & checkbox html+Script:

[image: Chechbox and selector code]

Enabling function:

```
$("#checkbox").bind("click", function () {

     if ($('#checkbox').is(":checked"))
          {  alert("checked");
            $("#sel").attr('disabled',false);

          }
    else 
          {
            //Do nothing
          }
});
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad, welcome to SO. Please post code always as formatted text and not as screenshots.

Comment: You seem to be using a plugin called `multiselect`. Such plugins changes the markup and creates the dropdown from other elements, meaning any answer you get here likely won't work, as you haven't informed us of everything.

Comment: @adeneo i have this tutorial http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/

Answer (score 0):

using multiselect, try this:

```
$('#example-getting-started').removeAttr('disabled');

// And maybe, refresh the plugin
$('#example-getting-started').multiSelect('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you're using the id `"sel"` as the selector within your **jQuery**, when that is not defined within your **HTML**.

So, I've gone ahead and changed that to `"#example-getting-started"`. Along with changing the value of the disabled attribute to `"false"`, as opposed to `false`.

```
$(document).on("click", function(e){
    if($("#checkbox").is(":checked")){
        alert("Checked");
        $("#example-getting-started").attr("disabled", "false");
    }
});
```

Hopefully, this works for you! :)

Answer (score -1):

disable item is logically not editable, you need to remove the attribute

```
element.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

Comment: It's not .removeAttribute, it's just .removeAttr

Comment: Actually it's neither, it should be `element.prop('disabled', false)` as it's a property

Comment: @Difster Talha is correct, it's javascript not jQuery . Check the documentation here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_removeattribute.asp

Comment: the OP specifically asked for jQuery.

Comment: $( elem ).prop('disabled', false) is the best answer

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$("#sel").removeAttr('disabled');
```